Upper bound of Hurwitz zeta like function in two dimensions in terms of the parameter
Let $n>0$ a real number. I'm looking to bound the series
$$
\sum_{m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{N}} \dfrac{1}{(m_1+n)^2+(m_2+n)^2}
$$
In terms of $n$. The series converges as
$$
\sum_{m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{N}} \dfrac{1}{(m_1+n)^2+(m_2+n)^2} \le \sum_{m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{N}} \dfrac{1}{(m_1)^2+(m_2)^2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{N}} \dfrac{1}{(m_1)^2+(m_2)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{k^2} \frac{1}{k^2}
$$
where $c_{k^2}$ is the number of ways $k^2$ can be written as a sum of two squares that is
$$
c_{k^2}= D_1(k^2)-D_3(k^2)
$$
where $D_1,D_3$ are the number of divisor of $k^2$ congruent to $1,3 \mod(4)$ (see here).
The number of divisors of $k^2$ can be bounded by $k^{2\frac{1.5379 \log(2)}{\log(2\log(k))}}$ (see this aswer) and so
$$
\sum_{m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{N}} \dfrac{1}{(m_1+n)^2+(m_2+n)^2} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2 \left(1-\frac{1.5379 \log(2)}{\log(2\log(k))}\right)}
$$
and for $k>67$ the exponent is bigger then $1$.
But I have no idea how to bound the function in terms of $n$. Based on the one dimensional version I think the function czan be bounded by $1/n^2$, but I can't think any way to even start facing the problem

$$\sum_{m_1=1}^K\sum_{m_2=1}^K\frac{1}{(m_1+n)^2+(m_2+n)^2}\sim\ln K\to\infty ,,\text{at},,K\to\infty$$
